# Difference Azure Reserved IP address vs Azure static public address

Tags: azure

I tried to reserve IP address but It was thowirng error with with Reserved IP address, but Create public Static IP does work.

Is there any difference or limitation between these two type of static IP adress?

Thanks

Comment: Im trying to connect to you on the Stackoverflow chat

Comment: I am not able to see chat option here

Comment: You dont have enough points to use the chat. 

Please elaborate what you are trying to achive, how you are trying to do it and exactly what step is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved IP address is when you bring an Public IP-address/range that you have bought to Azure. Microsoft is not selling IP addresses so you need to buy that elsewhere.

Static IP will give you a Public Microsoft IP that will be reserved for you until you release it but its still Microsoft that owns the address and you will get the address randomly from Microsofts IP-Ranges.

Comment: I see, but I got this error during creation of Reserved IP adress `The operation is not permitted for namespace 'Microsoft.ClassicNetwork'` then How I can bring IP to this class>